# Chart js tooltip only being visible on the first data point

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm using chart js in my next js website and have created a line chart the problem is when I hover on the data points the tooltip is supposed to show up.

But in my case only the first tooltip is visible and the rest aren't

I have tried adding various props such as setting the mode to "index" even tried setting the mode to "nearest" but still only the first tooltip is visible and the rest arent

here is the code =>

`interface ChartCanvas extends HTMLCanvasElement {
chart?: any;
}

const ProfileIndex = () => {

```
const canvasRef = useRef(null);


useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current as ChartCanvas;
        if (canvas.chart) {
            canvas.chart.destroy();
        }

        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')!;

        const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, '#D3EBF7');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4392, '#34B3F1');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5386, '#003488');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.6441, '#003488');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.8534, '#34B3F1');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.9864, '#D5EDF8');

        canvas.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '',
                    data: [100, 20, 80, 40, 60, 20, 70],
                    borderColor: gradient,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    tension: 0.4,
                    borderCapStyle: 'round',
                    borderJoinStyle: 'round',
                    pointRadius: 4,
                    pointBackgroundColor: gradient 
                }]
            },
            
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        display: false
                    },
                    x: {
                        display: false
                    }
                },
                interaction: {
                    intersect: true,
                    mode: "index"
                },
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    }
                },
                
            },
            
        });
    }
}, []);



return (
    <div>
        <div className="flex mt-24 md:mt-0 justify-evenly items-start gap-28 md:gap-24 lg:gap-0 flex-wrap">

            <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-6 md:mt-16 lg:mt-24 xl:mt-0">
                <div className='w-[47rem] h-[24rem]'>
                    <div className="max-h-[500px] max-w-[1220px] flex items-center justify-center relative">
                        <div className="z-30 text-white md:-top-[3%] -top-[4%] left-[37%] sm:left-[17%]  absolute">
                            <h1 className="lg:text-2xl sm:text-xl text-base font-normal text-[#A3C7D7]">
                                ACTIVITY
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className=" w-[100%] h-[20rem] bg-[#43E5F1] border-[#43E5F1] border-[1px] flex justify-center items-center custom-shapeMobile custom-shape">
                            <div className="w-[100%] h-[100%] custom-shapeMobile2 custom-shape2 text-white bg-[#060709] opacity-[99]">
                                <div className='pt-12 w-full'>
                                 

                                    <div className="w-[45rem] h-[18rem] relative z-10">
                                        <canvas ref={canvasRef} className='profileChart' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default ProfileIndex`

Comment: Using the your config, https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/ZEqrNde, sounds working....

Comment: wow yes it is but why is it not working in my code any idea. Can you pls help I genuinely need to fix this Its my first junior dev job and cannot afford to make a mistake, Could you pleaseeee help me out

Comment: I just figured out the problem is if I set custom width and height then only the first tool-tip is visible but the moment I remove the width and height then all the tool-tips are again visible. But inorder to follow the ui design I need to set custom width and height

Comment: Maybe in this case you can try setting 'responsive: false' to the chart options.

Comment: But why would I set responsive to false because I want the chart to be looking good on other smaller devices as well